# Redirect additional domains to main .com domain using IIS7 URL Rewrite Module

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

How should I configure the URL Rewrite Rule in IIS7 to redirect my aditional domains ( domain.net, domain.org, domain.info) to the principal .com domain?

Comment: You can use the GUI to setup a redirect in IIS7 per [this](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-http-redirection/2008-03-27/) post.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS7, you can use the new command “appcmd.exe” to enable redirection as following:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "Default Web Site/" -section:system.webServer/httpRedirect -enabled:true -destination:"http://domain.com"
```

This tells IIS to redirect all request sending to the virtual application “/” to “http://domain.com”. The actual result is that appcmd.exe adds the following section to the web.config file for “/”:

web.config of your domain.net

```
<system.webServer>

    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent"/>

</system.webServer>
```